# Diff with -d and -pNum patching under arbitrary path

Tags: linux, diff

I create patch: `diff repo/abc/def/file1 repo/abc/def/file2 > pkg.patch`

`repo` is under `/home/user`

Patching with this command under arbitrary path in the current system:

```
cd /somewhere/in/heaven
patch -d/home/user/repo -p2 < /home/user/repo/abc/def/file1
```

I think the above patching is correct but not quite sure, can someone confirm?

If yes that would confirm for `patch` will combine `-d` and `-p` option to caculate the current `pwd` of patching and the path of file1 that appears in patch file - `repo/abc/def/file1`. `-pNum` with `Num` relative to `-d`.

Comment: You are thinking backwards, `-pnum` is *"Strip  the smallest* **prefix** *containing `num` leading slashes"*. So if your patchfile has a path `/home/user/repo/abc/def/file1` and you change to `/home/user/repo` using `-d`, you need **-p3** to strip `/home/user/repo`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: But in this case my patchfile will has path like `repo/abc/def/file1` then when `-d` make `cd` to `/home/user/repo` and do patching under this folder, the `patch` actually is `abc/def/` and I have to pass `-p2` only.

Comment: Then you would need `-p1` to strip the `repo/` from the beginning to allow the patch to proceed using the *relative path* `abc/def/file1`.

Comment: I see, so that `patch` command would have its absolute `path` to process `/home/user/repo/abc/def/file1`

Comment: So the *resulting path* would have an *absolute path* of `/home/user/repo/abc/def/file1` BUT `patch` (executed from `/home/user/repo`) would use the relative path `abc/def/file1` matching the location of where `file1` is located after you have told `patch` to `-d` (change to) `/home/user/repo`.